# Making an element extend outside its parent with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working with some mark-up where we have a number of html blocks/controls sitting within an outer container, this container is basically a foundation row with a max-width.

In certain situations I need blocks to break out of this container, to extend beyond the max-width and occupy the full width, but remain in it's original position in terms of index. Stay with me! This looks as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div><em>Regular block here</em></div>
    <div class="full-width"><em>Full width block here</em></div>
    <div><em>Regular block here</em></div>
</div>
```

In effect what I want to have is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div><em>Regular block here</em></div>
</div>       
<div class="full-width"><em>Full width block here</em></div>
<div class="row">
    <div><em>Regular block here</em></div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately we don't have access to do this properly in html so jQuery looks our best bet.

I tried doing something like this, but to no avail as it's not correctly formatted html:

```
$('div.row > .full-width').each(function() {
    $(this).before('</div>').after('<div>');
});
```

Anyone got any ideas of achieving this, without completely writing the whole DOM out again, otherwise I'll have to reapply a load of bindings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can probably accomplish this with CSS alone. Please put a working demo up. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Yeah i'd rather not go down the css route, I looked at using negative margins etc, but was running into cross-browser issues.

Comment: Still, a starting-point demo would go a long way to getting more responses.

Comment: @isherwood, I agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cftpd3t2/1/)**

First **[`unwrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)** the `.full-width` element. This remove the main `.row`, then **[`wrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/)** the next and previous elements in `.row`.

```js
$('div.row > .full-width').each(function() {
  var $rowDiv = $('<div class="row">');
  $(this).unwrap('.row');
  $(this).prev().wrap($rowDiv);
  $(this).next().wrap($rowDiv);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div><em>Regular block here</em></div>
    <div class="full-width"><em>Full width block here</em></div>
    <div><em>Regular block here</em></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row" id="oldrow">
    <div><em>Regular block here</em></div>
    <div class="full-width" id="fwblk"><em>Full width block here</em></div>
    <div id="rgblk"><em>Regular block here</em></div>
</div>
```

The following DOM will remove the two `div`s and add them afterwards

```
body = document.body;  // body or the container
oldrow = document.getElementById("oldrow");
fwblk = document.getElementById("fwblk");
rgblk = document.getElementById("rgblk");
newRow = document.createElement("div");
newRow.className="row";
oldrow.removeChild(fwblk);
oldrow.removeChild(rgblk);
newRow.appendChild(rgblk);
// insert to body
body.appendChild(fwblk);
body.appendChild(newRow);
```

This will "hopefully" solve your problem with just simple JavaScript. Although, more logical and extensible code can be written with that in mind.
This will probably be enough for you to get going

The body holds  the container
then we're retrieving the old row (an identifier works the best)
retrieving fwblk and rgblk (fullwidth block and regular blocks)
creating a new div at newRow and set the class name to `row`
removing fwblk and rgblk from old block
adding rgblk to newRow
finally, adding fgblk and newRow to body hence injecting them to the `body`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `unWrap`, `next` and `andSelf`. In this way you can get the element itself and the following and unwrap them from its parent.

Ref:

- https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/
- https://api.jquery.com/andself/

Code:

```
$('div.row > .full-width').each(function() {
    $(this).next(':not(".full-width")').andSelf().unwrap();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kLw6sv29/